# A "line" around an unselected layer in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using Adobe InDesign CC.

Whenever I create a square using the rectangle tool, a 'green line' is shown around it (I'm not sure how to call it).

Up until now, such a 'green line' was only shown around a SELECTED (active) layer; but for some reason, it is now shown permanently, even though another layer is selected, and even if the original layer is locked. Please see the screenshots attached.

I'd be glad to know how I can get rid of this 'green line'.

Thanks in advance for your kind help :-)

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unlike paths, you can see the nonprinting strokes (outlines) of frames by default even when the frames aren’t selected.

To show or hide frame edges, choose View → Extras → Show/Hide Frame Edges

[Adobe Indesign Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/laying-out-frames-pages.html/show_or_hide_frame_edges)